# Different results when running in LLVM and gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, llvm

A few days ago, a script that ran on my laptop ran differently than running it on another Linux box (the scripts I ran are identical to each other). My guess is that my compiler is missing something. I don't know what the problem is though.

After running g++ -v, this is the result I get:

```
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

After running g++ -v on this other Linux box, I'm getting:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada,go,lto --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --disable-libgcj --with-isl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.3-20140911/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/isl-install --with-cloog=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.3-20140911/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/cloog-install --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=x86-64 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9) (GCC)
```

The following script is a script to calculate shortest path to all vertices from one source vertex, in this case it's vertex 1. The output of this script lists every single vertex and its shortest distance to it from the source. The input file in question is also listed below. Here's my script in question:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

struct Node{
    int dist;
    int v;

    bool operator==(const Node& a){
        return dist == a.dist;
    }

    bool operator!=(const Node& a){
        return (!(dist  == a.dist));
    }

    bool operator<(const Node& a){
        return dist < a.dist;
    }
    bool operator>(const Node& a){
        return a.dist < dist;
    }
    int operator+(const Node& a){
        return a.dist+dist;
    }
};

struct cheapHeap{
    int curSize;
    Node * minHeap;
};

class DijkstraSolution{

    private:
        int size;
        int sourceV;
        list<Node> *container; //this is the container to hold input data
        int *results;          //this is the array to hold final results
        cheapHeap ch;          //this is the array that holds each dist looked at

    public:
        DijkstraSolution(string fname, int inSourceV, int inSize): size(inSize), sourceV(inSourceV){

            //read the file and initialize the list<Node> container
            container = new list<Node>[size];

            ifstream infile;
            infile.open(fname.c_str());
            string line = "";

            if (infile){
                while (getline(infile, line)){
                    istringstream iss(line);
                    int vertex;
                    int v;
                    int dist;
                    iss >> vertex;
                    while(iss >> v >> dist){
                        Node edges;
                        edges.dist = dist;
                        edges.v = v;
                        container[vertex].push_back(edges);
                    }
                }
            }
            infile.close();

            //initialization of results and minHeap array
            int maxVal = numeric_limits<int>::max();
            results = new int[size];

            ch.curSize = size-1; 
            ch.minHeap = new Node[size];

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                results[i] = maxVal;
                ch.minHeap[i].dist = maxVal;
            }
            results[sourceV] = 0;
            ch.minHeap[sourceV].dist = 0;
            ch.minHeap[sourceV].v = sourceV;

        }

        //find min of all nodes inserted into minHeap
        Node findMin(){
            Node minimum;
            minimum.dist = numeric_limits<int>::max();
            minimum.v = 0;

            for (int i=1; i <= size; i++){
                if ((ch.minHeap[i] < minimum) && (ch.minHeap[i].dist != -1)){
                    minimum = ch.minHeap[i];

                }
            }
            ch.minHeap[minimum.v].dist = -1;
            ch.curSize--;
            return minimum;
        }

        //for every min that findMin() spits out, insert this min into the results array 
        int * dijkstra(){
            while (ch.curSize != 0){
                Node minimum = findMin(); 
                results[minimum.v] = minimum.dist; 

                for (list<Node>::iterator it = container[minimum.v].begin(); it != container[minimum.v].end(); it++){
                    if ((*it)+minimum < ch.minHeap[(*it).v].dist){
                        Node inserted;
                        inserted.dist = *it + minimum;
                        inserted.v = (*it).v;
                        ch.minHeap[(*it).v] = inserted;

                    }
                }
            }
            return results;
        }

        //this prints the contents from the file input
        void printContainer(){
            for (int i=1; i < size; i++){
                cout << i << " ";
                list<Node>::iterator iter;
                for (iter = container[i].begin(); iter != container[i].end(); iter++){
                    cout << iter -> v << " " << iter -> dist << " ";
                }
                cout <<endl;
            }
        }

        //this prints out the contents from the results array   
        void printResults(){
            for (int i = 1; i < size; i++){
                cout << i << " -> " << results[i] << endl;
            }
        }
};

int main(){

    DijkstraSolution ds("pa5_test1.txt", 1, 9);

    ds.dijkstra(); 
    ds.printResults();

}
```

This is my input file:

```
1   2 1 8 2
2   1 1 3 1
3   2 1 4 1
4   3 1 5 1
5   4 1 6 1
6   5 1 7 1
7   6 1 8 1
8   7 1 1 2
```

This is the output I'm getting from my Mac, which is incorrect:

```
1 -> 0
2 -> 2147483647
3 -> 2147483647
4 -> 2147483647
5 -> 2147483647
6 -> 2147483647
7 -> 2147483647
8 -> 2147483647
```

This is the output I'm getting from the other Linux box, which is correct:

```
1 -> 0
2 -> 1
3 -> 2
4 -> 3
5 -> 4
6 -> 4
7 -> 3
8 -> 2
```

Apparently, my compiler is not updating the results array. Apparently, it updates the first entry to 0, and then it just stops updating it. This is really strange because I've run the same exact code on different boxes and the results are the same as the Linux box, so I'm guessing it's my compiler. What is frustrating is that I'm not getting any errors, so I don't even know where to begin looking for an answer. Also, not sure if this is related, but when I fire up gdb, it doesn't debug a script that is written as a class. It only debugs code that has a main and functions, it trips when I write a main function that instantiates some class. If my compiler is indeed broken, any suggestions (baby steps) as to how to rebuild it? Sorry for the long post.

Comment: Just a note: A C++ code is not a script. Scripts are interpreted.

Comment: got it, so is code or program a better choice?

Comment: AFAIK you can just run `gdb` on any binary executable, it doesn't matter how it's compiled or what language it was written in. You may get assembly code and symbol names and no debug information, but it would work. Are you sure you have the file `pa5_test1.txt` on your mac?

Comment: yes, pa5_test1.txt is in my mac, I've also tried with different files, and it's the same output.

Comment: Hm. Your program also produces that exact same output if there is no file. Add some checks and logging.

Comment: ok, so I started using some print statements, and it seems that it is not reading the comparison between nodes properly, even after I have overloaded the <, the findMin() spits out 0 every single iteration.

Comment: Could you turn off any optimisation flags and run again. pass -O0 as optimisation flag.

Comment: On a side note -- what's with all of these calls to `new`?  Why not just use `std::vector`, similar to how you use `std::list`?

Comment: @Ashkan is this the way to run it, `g++ -O0 dijkstra_no_heap.cpp ` if so, it's giving me the same output.

Comment: @jasonadams yes that is the syntax. The reason I asked for this is that sometimes when compiler tries to optimise your code, it reorders the instructions. In rare cases this can cause issues like what you have.

Comment: @Ashkan, would it be premature to say that my compiler is messed up?

Comment: @jasonadams Guess what -- if you used `std::vector` and used `vector::at( )`, you would see that you're going out of bounds, causing undefined behavior.  See what happens when you don't use the tools available to you?  Given your code and data, this line in `findMin` : `ch.minHeap[minimum.v].dist = -1;`  throws an exception that the minimum.v is a crazy number when run in Visual Studio.  If you used `vector::at()`, all of that checking would be done for you.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie could you elaborate as to this behavior, is it because I'm not initializing minimum.v?

Comment: @jasonadams I changed your code to use `std::vector` and `at()`, and discovered the error in your code, as my answer shows.  See this redo of your code using `std::vector` and the `at( )` function.  When you get the bugs out of it, then you can change `at( )` to `[ ]`  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f96182e75d87dd76

Comment: Also, I would keep the `at()` in there until all of the out-of-bounds accesses are cleared up.  However that does not guarantee you will get the right answer -- it is just to ensure you're not invoking undefined behavior by going beyond the bounds of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue is this:

```
    for (int i=1; i <= size; i++){  // <-- Index goes out of bounds here
        if ((ch.minHeap[i] < minimum) && (ch.minHeap[i].dist != -1)){
            minimum = ch.minHeap[i];
```

You are looping to `size`, but `minHeap[size]` is an out-of-bounds access.

Comment: I feel dumb. Any idea why this wrong code worked on other boxes?

Comment: Going beyond the bounds of an array is *undefined behavior*.  So truthfully, the code wasn't really working, only by luck.